# How can we make bootstrap-wysihtml5 plugin work only for the input tags not for the list and pictures and other part of program?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/
What can we change in javascript file of this his plugin so that it only works for input tag of the program not in other parts like tag,popover,links,potos.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what the problem is. The plugin is meant to be invoked on a `textarea`, not an `input`. I don't see what it has to do with popovers, links etc.

Comment: When we use this plugin it works for images links labels so how can we prevent this and make it work only for text area.when i use this plugin it showed the red underline in the name of the links so how can we prevent this and make it work only for textareas.

Comment: You simply attach it to the textarea. `$('.your-textarea').wysihtml5();`